# Laravel 8 "The requested resource /dashboard was not found on this server."

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I try to make login with laravel 8 jetstream, but i have error like

> The requested resource /dashboard was not found on this server.

when login success and try to how the dashboard page, can somebody help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you created a folder on `public` directory called `dashboard`, that conflict with your route URI

Comment: my fould, thanks its work after i change my dashboard folder in public directory